# I want to make a pause button on the scene

Tags: c#, unity, unityscript

I want to make a pause button on the scene. If I press the button it will show the `guiTexture` with a variety of buttons with each different script. So what steps should I take? 
1. How do make it so if I press the pause button on a scene it will show guiTexture?

[image: prototype]

Comment: What do you have so far? What part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use NGUI here and save yourself from the trouble. Another would be to use a boolean flag which will be set to true on clicking the red button.

To give you some idea on how to use the flag method, you can use this code-snippet -

```
void OnGUI(){
    //Other GUI functions, such as drawing the red button
    if(pause_flag) //pause_flag is your boolean flag which will set to true only if you press the red button
    {
        //Code to draw your GUITexture and other buttons which will appear on clicking the pause button.
        //You can put a close button which will set the flag to false again to hide the texture.
    }
}
```

I hope the logic is clear enough for you to understand.